# what does the -> operator means and usages in grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am new working with grails application.I am confusing about this -> operator in grails.
Can anyone give me clear concept about this?
or Give me any reference about this that can be easy for me.
I am already reading online documentation and some books but i am still confusing about this operator and usages.

Comment: Read about [closures](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the parameter indicator in a Groovy closure. You can find out more about [closures here](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

`->` is a symbol indicating the end of parameters list for a closure in Groovy.

In the first example (given in comments) you have a closure called `printSum` and it takes two parameters; `a` and `b`:

```
def printSum = { a, b -> 
  print a+b 
}
```

In the second example (given in the comments) you have a named criteria called `oldPublicationsLargerThan` and it takes one parameter called `pageCount`.

```
oldPublicationsLargerThan { pageCount -> 
  def now = new Date() 
  lt 'datePublished', now - 365 
  gt 'numberOfPages', pageCount 
}
```

Comment: Here def printSum = { a, b -> print a+b } means a,b indicate print a+b  or something else?

Comment: oldPublicationsLargerThan { pageCount ->
           def now = new Date()
           lt 'datePublished', now - 365
           gt 'numberOfPages', pageCount
       } another example but still confused.can you explain about this?.

Comment: I don't understand how else can it be made clear. It is like why do we have `){` in a method declaration.

Comment: really useless and confuse

Answer (score 7):

That thin arrow is a parameter list delimiter.

The syntax for a closure parameter list can be roughly translated to the method parameter list.

This is the closure:

```
def criteria = { a, b ->
  return a + b
}
```

And this is the method version:

```
def criteria(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

Closures have more features, though.

Comment: You can also have a closure without this "thin arrow", and the first parameter will be automatically named 'it' by groovy.